# how to load the cxf wss4j crypto property file from external location other than the classpath

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

i am trying to externalize the crypto.properties files which is needed to sign the SOAP CXF request messages. 
According to the framework it should have the property file in the classpath.
I am not able to load it from external. Please help me , i have tried a lot of techniques.

i am getting the below exception

org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: General security error (Cannot load the resource file:

it is very necessary to externalize the file as we have synced up our development and production environment code base

The CXF framework used is 2.6.10

Comment: the framework is cxf 2.6.10

Comment: Aw snap, I've also hit this, and can't be pinned on CXF. It's a WSS4J limitation, and IMO a serious CM/Infosec limitation. The semantics of WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE are lame.

Comment: FWIW, made this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-540

Comment: You should probably add some more information about your runtime environment. Are you running this on an application server?

Answer (score 7):

As noted in Colm O hEigeartaigh's answer it is possible to load the configuration settings from an external file using recent versions of CXF and WSS4J. However, this still means needing to write the properties to a file and loading them again.

You can also construct a Properties object in-memory, and have CXF use that instead. This also works for older CXF versions. This is done by extending `WSS4JInInterceptor` and `WSS4JOutInterceptor`, and then overriding the `Crypto loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(String propFilename, RequestData reqData)` method and just returning your own `Crypto` object, which you can create using `CryptoFactory.getInstance(properties)`.

So something like:

```
Properties cxfProps = new Properties();
cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider", "org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin");
cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type", "jks");
cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", "client");
cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", PASSWORD);
cxfProps.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", "keystore.j2");

Crypto crypto = CryptoFactory.getInstance(cxfProps);

Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();

inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "dummy_value"); // Only necessary to avoid NPE

outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Signature");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "client");
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_FILE, "dummy_value"); // Only necessary to avoid NPE

WSS4JInInterceptor wssIn = new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps) {
  @Override
  protected Crypto loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(String propFilename, RequestData reqData)
      throws WSSecurityException {
    return crypto;
  }
};
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps) {
  @Override
  protected Crypto loadCryptoFromPropertiesFile(String propFilename, RequestData reqData)
      throws WSSecurityException {
    return crypto;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It is supported, see my comment here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-540